# Some topics with all-equal weights when using LatentDirichletAllocation from scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I want to employ Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) for topic modeling and I'm trying out the implementation from scikit-learn for that.

Running the [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-topics-extraction-with-nmf-lda-py) (which uses messages from newsgroups as documents) from scikit's documentation works just fine and delivers reasonable results, but when I'm trying out any other data set, I get some very strange results. For example, when I'm using the 18 documents from the Gutenberg corpus provided with NLTK and fit a topic model with 30 topics, many of those topics are essentially the same and have all-equal weights (each weight equal to the `topic_word_prior` parameter), see for example the following output:

```
Topic #0: zoological (0.01) fathoms (0.01) fatigued (0.01) fatigues (0.01) fatiguing (0.01)
Topic #1: mr (1081.61) emma (866.01) miss (506.94) mrs (445.56) jane (301.83)
Topic #2: zoological (0.01) fathoms (0.01) fatigued (0.01) fatigues (0.01) fatiguing (0.01)
Topic #3: thee (82.64) thou (70.0) thy (66.66) father (56.45) mother (55.27)
Topic #4: anne (498.74) captain (303.01) lady (173.96) mr (172.07) charles (166.21)
Topic #5: zoological (0.01) fathoms (0.01) fatigued (0.01) fatigues (0.01) fatiguing (0.01)
Topic #6: zoological (0.01) fathoms (0.01) fatigued (0.01) fatigues (0.01) fatiguing (0.01)
Topic #7: zoological (0.01) fathoms (0.01) fatigued (0.01) fatigues (0.01) fatiguing (0.01)
...
```

Code:

```
import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation

def print_top_words(model, feature_names, n_top_words):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        message = "Topic #%d: " % topic_idx
        message += " ".join([feature_names[i] + " (" + str(round(topic[i], 2)) + ")"
                             for i in topic.argsort()[:-n_top_words - 1:-1]])
        print(message)


all_docs_en = {f_id: nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw(f_id)
               for f_id in nltk.corpus.gutenberg.fileids()}

data_samples = all_docs_en.values()

tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2,
                                stop_words='english')
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(data_samples)

lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=30,
                                learning_method='batch',
                                n_jobs=-1,  # all CPUs
                                verbose=1,
                                evaluate_every=10,
                                max_iter=1000,
                                doc_topic_prior=0.1,
                                topic_word_prior=0.01,
                                random_state=1)

lda.fit(tf)
tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, 5)
```

Changing some parameters didn't help, but using a different Python implementation (e.g. the [lda](http://pythonhosted.org/lda/) package) results in reasonable topics. However, I need to use scikit-learn because it runs on multiple processors, hence I'm a bit stuck here. I'm wondering if there might be a bug in the implementation or if I'm missing something.

I should add that I'm using Python 2.7 and scikit-learn 0.19.0.

Comment: Have you tried if with different random_state parameters, and if so did you observe the same result?

Comment: Same. It doesn't depend on the `random_state`. However, I noticed similar, but not as extreme, behavior when using Gensim, which also uses the Variational Bayes approach. Could it be the Variational Bayes approach is problematic when having only a small number of (though quite big) documents? Or do I have to adjust the parameters somehow in this case?

Comment: Rereading, I see that you've set `num_topics` to less than the size of the corpus. I'd give it a try with `num_topics << N`.

Answer (score 1):

In a small discussion in the scikit-learn mailinglist, we came to the [conclusion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/scikit-learn/2017-September/001941.html) that the number of documents is indeed to few for the algorithm to learn informative topics from it. However, this is really a limitation of the Online Variational Bayes (Hoffman et al) approach which is implemented in scikit-learn for LDA (the same approach is also used in Gensim). If I split the documents into "sub-documents" with, say, 5 paragraphs each (giving ~10k of such sub-documents), the algorithm is able to find informative topics.

Gibbs sampling based implementations like [lda](http://pythonhosted.org/lda/), on the other hand, handle scenarios with a small number of (large) documents better.